# Why don't fixed elements accept max-width?

Tags: html, css

First of all, I can't post any code here as the problem is with my **[blog](http://www.vkcreativework.blogspot.com)**.
Please open this. Now, there are 2 problems, actually.

**Main problem:**

If you notice the content on the top, which is actually the **header** containing my blog's title, has **fixed** position. Same is with the div just below it, that is my **navigation** panel (div with class **tabs-outer**). Both these elements have max-width: 1090px, BUT IT"S NOT WORKING. Is there any way so that these elements are fixed and also accept max-width?

**Problem 2:**

Second thing is that, when you decrease the screen width of your browser, the div having main content (i.e., div with class **content-outer**) contracts, as I have set max-width property for it. But the problem is that when you open this blog in any **smartphone**, it doesn't follow it. The blog opens with 1090px width. Why is it happening? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why are you setting the header to a max-width of 1090px when the content is only 767px?

Comment: I want it to be of equal width with rest of the content.

Comment: I want to give it flexible width. It should decrease its width when browser width is decreased, just like rest of the content of the blog.

Comment: May I suggest you accept the answer from @Danny Mahoney. For future project you may want to checkout a grid system like bootstrap or flexbox.

Comment: I could but that solution doesn't solve my problem. It is just like a patch work.

Answer (score 1):

**Main Problem:** your code seems to be doing nothing unexpected. Perhaps you misunderstand the use of `max-width`. What exactly do you want the outcome to be? If you want the below effect:

[image: Vikas Kumar's Blog]

Then, simply change:

`header`'s `max-width: 1090px` to `width:100%;max-width:1090px`

AND

`.tabs-outer`'s `max-width: 1090px` to `width:100%;max-width:1090px;`

**Problem 2:**

Assuming the above does not get you the effect you are after on mobile device, use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to specify CSS based on screen size. Here is an example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){ 

.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li{ 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 34px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    border-left: none; 
    border-right: none; 
    background-color: #19697b; 
} 

.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li:selected{ 
    background-color: #19697b; 
} 

.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li a{ 
    z-index: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
} 

}
```

(This example would be one step to better utilizing the space for smaller screens, here is the result:

[image: Example Media Query Result]

Comment: Let's discuss about first problem first. When I set max-width to width, it won't decrease its width when I reduce browser's width. I want it to be flexible as the rest of the blog's content.

Comment: Then do this... 

width:1090px;
max-width:100%;

Comment: That's really fine. But I have doubt. Does it hide the width or actually decreases the width when browser width is decreased? Because we have 'fixed' the width to 1090px!

Comment: If it were more than 100% of the screen then a horizontal scrollbar will appear, I will add this correct solution to my answer for "Main Problem"

Comment: I still don't understand how width and max-width work together. Please explain if you could.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use this method. As it doesn't seem good. It actually doesn't reduce the element's width when needed. It does something else.

Comment: max-width means that it specifies a maximum width, so max-width:100% means that it cannot have a greater width than the parent. I JUST REALIZED! I did it backwards, so it should be `width:100%;max-width:1090px`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116370/discussion-between-danny-mahoney-and-vikas-kumar).

Answer (score -1):

When I inspect your page I see this on: home.html:162

```
   html body .region-inner {
        min-width: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
```

If you remove this the width of your nav panels is fine.